# Replace string in jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace a string with another string but that is not working for me. I brief I am trying to replace a smiley string with a smiley image, but that is not working. Please take a look at code and let me know what is wrong with it:

```
var comment ="Hello all how are you :)";
var emo = {'smile': ':)', 'tongue': ':P'};

$.each(emo,function(index,value) {
    if(comment.contains(value)){

        var emopiclink = 'http://www.abcdedif.com/emoticon/'+index+'.png'; 
        var emopic = '<img src="'+emopiclink+'" hieght="20px" width="20px">';

        comment.replace(value, emopic);
        console.log(comment);
        // alert("String Found");
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: There is no error @Pointy

Comment: There's no `.contains()` function on the String prototype. I think you want `if (comment.indexOf(value) >= 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to accept the returned value from `replace()` method and there is no `contains` use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
var comment = "Hello all how are you :)";
var emo = {
  'smile': ':)',
  'tongue': ':P'
};

$.each(emo, function(index, value) {
  if (comment.indexOf(value) > -1) {
    var emopiclink = 'http://www.abcdedif.com/emoticon/' + index + '.png';
    var emopic = '<img src="' + emopiclink + '" hieght="20px" width="20px">';
    comment = comment.replace(value, emopic);
    console.log(comment);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: its work now but  image is not coming in its position where the smiley should be place what is the solution for it

Comment: @AzadChouhan, How you are using `comment` after string replacement?